# My computer does not use DCHP, it only uses default adress? No network access

Tags: networking, dhcp

Recently one of my computer's network connection stopped to work. When I did an ipconfig I saw that the NIC was using the IP address outside the range of my DCHP server, something like "168.254.60.120(default), 255.255.0.0" instead of 192.168.1.74/24 witch the router has given the computer. All other computers on the network are working, so it is not an issue with the router. The troubled computer is indeed using DHCP and not the above /16 adress. I tried to hardcode the IP address under IPv4 settings but it doesent work.

Any ideas?

The computer is a laptop from Asus with a broadcom NIC, running Windows 7.

Comment: If you see 169.254.X.X/16 address you are in trouble as it is the auto-configuration address (link-local), which means you pretty much cannot communicate with anyone because you neither got an address from DHCP server, nor did you specify it manually. What address did you try to hardcode?

Comment: First try pinging the static address (from another machine on the network) you are trying to assign to see if it is not taken by other machine, as if you assign a used one to your laptop, it will fail

Answer (score 2):

Your 169 is a glitch of sorts, you need to release your lan ip and get a 192... ip. you can try restarting a few times, but this usually does the trick.

> Method 1

1. Click the Start menu button on the Windows taskbar. Click Run... on this menu.
2. If the computer is holding a current IP address, type 'cmd' (without the quotes) in the text box that appears. A command prompt window appears on the screen.
3. Type 'ipconfig' (without the quotes) to view the status of the computer's IP address(es).
4. If the computer is holding a current IP address, type 'ipconfig /release' to let go of the address.
5. Type 'ipconfig /renew' to obtain a new IP address (whether or not the computer is holding a current address).

> Method 2:

You can also try to manually set a 192 ip address in your TCP/IP Properties.

Steps to get to this location:

step 1: Press start

[image]

step 2: Right click, goto properties

[image]

step 3: Enter this info, press ok

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sickest, but I've already tried these two methods. When I try to release the IP it gives an error message. When I try to put in the address manually it doesent change anything, and still no network access. Im going to try to reset the laptop to factory default, see if it helps. :)

Comment: setting your laptop to factory default is VERY dramatic, lol. uninstall your network drivers, and let windows re-install them. i've ran into this problem many times, this is 100% going to fix the problem

Comment: BTW. 169.254.x.x is not really "a glitch of sorts". It is the standard way to assign an IP when there is none available at the DHCP-host or the DHCP-host is not available. This is in accordance with [RFC 3927-standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3927). [Here](http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/sep/24/169-254-0-0-addresses-explained/) is an article explaining.

Comment: i know it's not. I was trying to explain the problem in a simple fashion, not everyone understands a technical explanation to the 10th degree of nerd.